# How do I create a drop down menu for viewing sub-reports in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report which has 4 sub-reports in it.

I want to have a drop down list on the parent report which has the names of each sub-report.

Based on the user selection, the sub-report will be visible.

Is this possible with SSRS? i'm very new to it and im just trying to figure everything out.

Comment: Yes it's possible.  Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  I would recommend having the parameter control the visibility settings on the sub reports.

For instance sub report 1 will have the Visibility setting of `=iif(Parameters!SubReportName.Value="SB1",false,true)`

sub report 2 would have the visibility setting of:

```
=iif(Parameters!SubReportName.Value="SB2",false,true)
```

And so forth.  The parameter you can just enter in the four available values which you will then set the visibility settings to.[image]